# Drei / Semi-transparent gray overlay on ImgImpl

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am facing a problem with ImageImpl that displays the images darker. I came to troubleshoot the problem which is actually a weird semi-transparent gray overlay that darken the images.

The project is from the official website of React Three Fiber. Here is the link if anyone have some time to help me.

I made it obvious for yall to see the problem by changing the image texture into a color that I've also put on the text to get a side by side comparison.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/infinite-scroll-forked-nc59vg?

I need to know what causes the gray overlay and how do I get rid of it.

Thanks !